# A complex variety with a finite non-abelian simple fundamental group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, homotopy-theory, fundamental-group

Does there exist a complex smooth proper variety whose fundamental group is finite non-abelian simple?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.  In fact, Serre proved that any finite group is the fundamental group of a smooth projective complex variety.  See Proposition 15 of:

J.-P. Serre, Sur la topologie des variétés algébriques en charactéristique $p$, Symposium Internacional de Topologia Algebraica, Universidad Nacional Autonoma de Mexico, 1958, pp. 24–53 ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=98097)).

Comment: The proof of this fact can also be found in Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry 2* (third edition), chapter 9, section 4.2. Another reference is *Fundamental Groups of Compact Kähler Manifolds* by Amorós et al., example 1.11.